# How to properly use a checkbox to enable and disable a button using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to get a checkbox to enable a button when it's checked or have the button disabled when the checkbox isn't checked and I just can't seem to get it to work properly. Currently I can click the checkbox but the button stays disabled. The checkbox successfully changes state from being checked to not, but the button doesn't reflect these changes. Anyone see the issues with my code and have any advice? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Checkbox code

```
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(17),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Flexible(
                                  child: Text(
                                "You agree by checking this box",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 7,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                          child: Container(
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 20,
                                  height: 20,
                                  child: new StatefulBuilder(
                                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                                        StateSetter setState) {
                                      return new Transform.scale(
                                        scale: 2.0,
                                        child: Checkbox(
                                          value: isCheck,
                                          checkColor: Colors.green,
                                          activeColor: Colors.grey,
                                          onChanged: (bool value) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              isCheck = value;
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Button Code

```
                                Container(
                                  width:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .45,
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .09,
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Verify Quarterly Report",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          fontSize: 14),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: isCheck ? () => submitReport() : null,
                                  ),
                                )
```

Comment: What do you mean I can't get it to work properly? What doesn't work? What did you get? What did you expect instead?

Comment: Just edit the question to include what it currently does. I'm wanting the button to be disabled when the checkbox  isn't checked and for it to be enabled when it is checked.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the `CheckBox` with a `StatefulBuilder`, if you do so, you aren't not triggering the rebuild of that widget itself by calling `setState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated and explained in my comment above, here is the code that works and demonstrate what you are trying to achieve:

You don't need to wrap your `CheckBox` with a `StatefulBuilder`, if you do some, `Flutter helps you create a widget that both has state and delegates its build to a callback.` hence triggering the `setState` doesn't trigger the `setState` of your initial `Screen` or `Widget`.

Here is a demo that works by eliminating the use of the `StatefulBuilder`.

```dart
   body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(17),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                    child: Text(
                  "You agree by checking this box",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 7,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    child: Transform.scale(
                      scale: 2.0,
                      child: Checkbox(
                        value: isCheck,
                        checkColor: Colors.green,
                        activeColor: Colors.grey,
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                          setState(() {
                            isCheck = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .45,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .09,
            child: RaisedButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.green,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: Text(
                "Verify Quarterly Report",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14),
              ),
              onPressed: isCheck ? () => submitReport() : null,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you a ton! Didn't even realize the StatefulBuilder would be causing that.

Comment: Glad it helped!